# Spring Integration TransactionSynchronizationFactory deleting file before Flow ends

Tags: spring-integration

Our `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` is deleting the source file even before the flow ends and this is causing a failure in the flow. After reading the file, we `split()`, make a `WebClient Gateway` call, `resequence()` and then `aggregate()`. Just after aggregation the `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` is performing a commit. Please suggest why is the behavior?

```
syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression("payload.delete()"));
syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression("payload.delete()"));

return Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofMinutes(pollInterval))
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory)
                .transactional(pseudoTransactionManager)
                .advice(loggingAdvice);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction synchronization is tied to a thread which has started transaction. Whenever you leave that thread (kinda unblock), the end of transaction is triggered. Be sure that you don't shift a message after that `aggregate()` to some other thread, e.g. via an `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel`.

In addition I would look into some other solution where you are not tied to transaction and threading model. Just have the file stored in the headers and whenever you done call its `delete()`! No reason to deal with transaction with simple files.

Comment: Thanq, believe the thread switching is done by `WebFlux`? Like you suggested we will go with simple `delete()`